# Swift UITableView / UICollectionVIew passing data to cell in cellForRowAt returns nil

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to pass a struct from collection view to its cells in cellForRowAt method. I also tried using table view but it produces the same bug.

Collection view class code:

```
class PaintingListCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    var allPaintings: CategorySection!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
    }
    
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allPaintings.paintings.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paintingCell", for: indexPath) as? PaintingCollectionViewCell
        
        // works perfectly
        cell?.paintingTitleLabel.text = allPaintings.paintings[indexPath.item].title
        cell?.paintingImageView.image = UIImage(named: allPaintings.paintings[indexPath.item].title)
        
        cell?.paintingData = allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.item]

        // prints out two valid data
        print(cell?.paintingData, allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.item])
    
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Cell class code:

```
class PaintingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var paintingImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var paintingNameLabel: UILabel!
    var paintingData: Painting?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // always returns nil, despite printing out the exact same thing in cellForItemAt returns a valid result. 
        print(paintingData)
    }

}
```

I am using following structs:

```
struct CategorySection {
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var color: UIColor
    var paintings: [Painting]
}

struct Painting {
    var title: String
    var size: String
    var year: String
    var text: String
}
```

What I found is that if I pass data directly to the cell's @IBOutlet UI properties, it works. But when I am passing data to an optional variable in UITableViewCell class, the result is always nil. This problem happens if I use UITableView too. Also, I need to mention that `var allPaintings: CategorySection!` in TableView class is also passed from another table view controller using the exact same way as described here. So the data passing occurring here is already the second time of the chain.

It is a very weird bug... I will be very thankful if anyone can help me!

EDITED: The original problem description uses UITable view instead of collection view, and sections instead of row for datasource. I made these changes for debugging purposes.

Comment: What “paintingData” looks like? And do you intentionally load each cell in section with the same data? Why use indexPath.section?

Comment: I just edited my post for more details. I am using section instead of row for styling purposes. I don't think it makes any difference when passing data.

Comment: Having sections and rows mixed up is logically incorrect. Your data source is not being setup correctly.

Comment: As far as the cell, I would unwrap all those optionals, starting with the cell and then keep going to find why painting stays nil.

Comment: I switched to row instead of section for "better logic". ```print( cell?.paintingData, allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.row])``` in cellForRowAt now produces two valid data now, but printing ```paintingData``` in the cell class still returns nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint on the print statements in awakeFromNib and in cellForRowAt, you will see that awakeFromNib gets called before you put the data into the collectionViewCell.  In fact it gets called by `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell()`. You want to use UICollectionViewCell.didMoveToSuperview()

```
class PaintingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var paintingImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var paintingNameLabel: UILabel!
    var paintingData: Painting?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        // always returns nil, despite printing out the exact same thing in cellForItemAt returns a valid result.
        print("Awake From Nib", paintingData)
    }
    
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        print ("did Move To Superview", paintingData)
    }
}
```

I added a guard to error check the cellForRowAt, if for some reason it fails to create the cell, the final line of the function will crash
`return cell!`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paintingCell", for: indexPath) as? PaintingCollectionViewCell else {
        fatalError("unable to dequeue cell")
    }
    
    // works perfectly
    cell.paintingNameLabel?.text = allPaintings.paintings[indexPath.item].title
    cell.paintingImageView.image = UIImage(named: allPaintings.paintings[indexPath.item].title)
    
    cell.paintingData = allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.item]
    
    // prints out two valid data
    print("cellForItemAt ",cell.paintingData ?? "nothing to see here", allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.item])
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Using row instead of section will always pass the first section of data to the cell...this is not what I want. Although ```print(cell?.paintingData, allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.section])``` in cellForRowAt prints two valid data now, ```print(paintingData)``` in ```awakeFromNib()``` in ```PaintingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell``` still returns nil...

Comment: Right.  I got my wires crossed there.  You need to use both the indexPath.section and indexPath.row to find the correct item in allPaintings. If all of your sections have the same number of rows, then you can access them with `realIndex = indexPath.section * numberOfItemsPerSection + indexPath.row`. then reference `allPaintings!.paintings[realIndex]` Otherwise paintings needs to be a two dimensional array so `paintings[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` returns what you are looking for

Comment: I switched to collection view, and uses collection view's equivalent of row: 'item''. And this bug still exists. Now I have many items and 1 section only. However, print( cell?.paintingData, allPaintings!.paintings[indexPath.row]) in cellForItemAt now produces two valid data now, but printing paintingData in the cell class still returns nil. Please see the edited problem description for details.

Comment: for collection views you use `indexPath.item` so you should replace all occurrences of `indexPath.row` with `indexPath.item`

Comment: sorry I did not update the post correctly. I was using item. And the issue still persists.

Comment: updated the answer, awakeFromNib is called by dequeueReusableCell, before you put the data in the cell,  willMoveToSuperview() gets called once the view is shown.

Comment: Yes! Using didMoveToSuperview() does solve this problem. Although I still do not fully understand how I should use these methods correctly at times. Also, setting the image to nil in prepareForReuse() now will make every images blank forever...